# Use Amazon Simple Notification service SNS with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-sns

I need to to use Amazon Simple Notification Service from a ruby-based application, and have no idea where to start.

Do you have any recommendations on where to start?

Answer (score 11):

To start with Amazon services, Follow the steps :

- Create account in [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/).
- Navigate to SNS service and create topic
- Install amazon aws sdk gem [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby). and open irb
- Here is sample code to invoke SNS services

  ```
  required "aws-sdk"

  Aws.config.update({region: 'your aws region',credentials:
  Aws::Credentials.new('aws access key', 'aws secret key')})

  c = Aws::SNS::Client.new(region: 'your aws region')

  c.operation_names #shows you list of operation you can do.

  c.publish({topic_arn: 'arn', message: "my message"})
  ```

Hope this would help you. Here are some more useful links :

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SNS.html
- http://aws.amazon.com/sns/details/

Comment: A snarky attitude in a response is not what we are trying to build in the SO community. You can communicate the guidance you gave without it being snarky.

Comment: @jordan. Okey that was little rude, I agree. But It is also important to improve the approach of development. By the way I have updated the answer.I hope now it looks good. :-)

Comment: That answer didn't sound at all snarky to me and seemed more complete than the one above.

Comment: @AnandSoni Nice job! I agree with improving the approach to finding answers, etc. But as my grandmother use to say,"You catch more flies with honey than with vinger..."; Of course, I also wondered why I wanted to catch flies in the first place :-) Thanks for taking my feedback in the spirit it was intended!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Amazon SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/). SNS is one of the services supported.